# PySide Asserts when preforming QTest.mouseClick on QTreeWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtestlib

If I try to use QTest.mouseClick on a QTreeWidget it raises an assert from the C++ library.

```
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from PySide.QtCore import Qt
from PySide.QtTest import QTest

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
tree = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
tree.headerItem().setText(0,"")
tree.headerItem().setText(1,"")
tree.headerItem().setText(2,"")
item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(tree)
item.setText(0,"a")
item.setText(1,"b")
item.setText(2,"c")
QTest.mouseClick(tree,Qt.LeftButton,pos=tree.visualItemRect(item).topLeft())

ASSERT: "QTest::testLogger" in file qtestlog.cpp, line 334
Abort trap: 6
```

I'm using PySide 1.2.2 and I've tried this on both OS X (10.9.3) and Windows7, both with the exact same result.

Am I doing something incorrect or did I discover a PySide bug (I'm fearing that the latter is the case)?

UPDATE:

The suggestion from @Trilarion gave me an idea.  I tried adding a parent to the QTreeWidget.  Doing that resolved the ASSERT, however the QTreeWidget does not seem to register the emulated click at all.

```
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from PySide.QtCore import Qt
from PySide.QtTest import QTest


def click():
    global tree,item
    print "Start Click"
    for x in xrange(0,1000):
        for y in xrange(0,1000):
            QTest.mouseClick(tree,Qt.LeftButton,pos=QtCore.QPoint(x,y))#tree.visualItemRect(item).topLeft())
    print "End click"


def was_clicked():
    print "Tree Was Clicked"

def beep():
    print "button was clicked"

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = QtGui.QWidget()
tree = QtGui.QTreeWidget(window)
tree.headerItem().setText(0,"")
tree.headerItem().setText(1,"")
tree.headerItem().setText(2,"")
item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(tree)
item.setText(0,"a")
item.setText(1,"b")
item.setText(2,"c")
tree.clicked.connect(was_clicked)
button = QtGui.QPushButton(window)
button.clicked.connect(beep)
#Sanity check to make sure that the button is registering the click
QTest.mouseClick(button,Qt.LeftButton)
#Overkill click test, try clicking the tree on every point in a 1000 x 1000 grid 
click()

button was clicked
StartClick
EndClick
```

I also tried running the above code in a unit test, didn't change the outcome.

Comment: Does it work in C++? If yes, your fearing might be valid, otherwise, I am not sure.

Comment: My suggestion would be to try the same in PyQt. If it works in PyQt, then it's probably a PySide bug.

Comment: Ok, I tried it with pyqt and I get the same error, so it looks like the issue is with my code.

Comment: Sorry, for not being able to help. I retracted my answer as it is obviously not solving the problem. The assert has gone away although it might be a bug. Why QTreeWidget is not registering the clicks I don't know.